# How to add hidden data to each row during creation in tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am building table with Tabulator5.2,
I need to pass some data to each row as hidden data like DB_ID ..etc
example:

```
{'extrId' : 10 , 'connectionDbIndex' : 101 }
```

In order to get the whole data when calling row.getData() or another method.

How i build the table:

This is the table headers:

```
var tableHeaders = 
[
    {formatter:"rowSelection", width:20 ,  titleFormatter:"rowSelection", hozAlign:"left", headerSort:false, cellClick:function(e, cell){cell.getRow().toggleSelect();}} ,
{title:'id", field:"ID"  , hozAlign:"left" ,responsive:2 ,  headerFilter:'input', headerFilterLiveFilter:true ,headerSort:false }
]
```

This is table data:

```
var i = 0
counter = 2000
while (i < counter){
        var more = {'DB_ID' : 2012 }
        var row = {id:1+i, name:"Oli Bob"+i, progress:12, gender:"male"+i, rating:1, col:"red", dob:"19/02/1984", car:1 , site:'new' , ticket:12 , opened:false , cssClass:class2.randomId() , data : {'s' : 10}}
        class2.insert_row(row , more)
        i++ 
    }
```

this is the function which responsible to add the rows:

```
insert_row(payload , more){
            this.tableContent.push(payload)
            this.rowMoreData.push(more)
            for (let key in payload ){
                var headerLabel = key
                if (! this.alreadyColumsAdded.includes(headerLabel)){
                    this.alreadyColumsAdded.push(headerLabel)
                    var a = {title:headerLabel, field:headerLabel  , hozAlign:"left" ,responsive:2 ,  headerFilter:'input', headerFilterLiveFilter:true ,headerSort:false }
                    this.tableHeaders.push(a)
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Once all rows added to the dict. Finally build the table.

```
var table = new Tabulator(this.tableId, this.tableOptions);
```

How is it possible to add some hidden data to each row?

Answer (score 0):

I do that too. I add `visible` to my column and set it to `false`.